# Is it possible to read a shapefile and save the resulting geopandas df so that I can then use the df without having to import geopandas?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, geopandas

```
import geopandas as gpd
street_map = gpd.read_file("States_shapefile-shp/States_shapefile.shp")
street_map.plot(ax=ax, alpha=1.0, color="grey")
```

Is it possible to save street_map one time and reuse that result. The lambda doesn't have the storage capacity for geopandas and matplotlib?

Comment: You can store the geometry as wkt (a string) and parse the wkt in shapely.

Comment: But then you won't have access to any of the geo-based methods (like `buffer` or `intersects` or anything like that).